# Does underfloor heating require screed?

Tags: tile, heating

We've just bought a house in the UK with underfloor heating, where the flooring tiles were clearly installed by a cowboy, dotted and dabbed straight onto the underfloor heating (which is water heated, and in some kind of silver casing - not quite sure what it is.)

We're having to get the whole floor ripped up and put back on properly. The only thing is, there seems to be some dispute among various builders as to whether screed has to go over the underfloor heating system, or it's OK to just put self-levelling compound over it, alongside ditra mat and adhesive.

It would make our lives quite difficult if it needs to be screeded, as it will bring the level of the floor up quite high - but of course, we want it done properly - not interested in a bodge job! Can anyone offer any advice?

[image]

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: there are no Cowboys in UK ! The silver foil is reflective foil

Comment: The more mass, the longer it takes for the floor to heat up.  The more mass, the floor stays warm for much longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a heating Engineer in the UK, self leveling compound is fine if tiling over again, the closer the pipe work is to the tile the better but must be covered. You will not require any Gas Safe Registered engineer intervenction, unless there is gas pipework in the self leveled  floor.

As A Note: The pipework should of been placed in a plastic moulded tray, this gives the pipe percific dimenctions between there spaceing and removes the need for a huge amout of leveling compound.

[image: Underfloor tray]